# time.sleep makes pictures in loop to not show

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, time

I've been trying to iterate over files in a folder and show them for two seconds each using this code:

```py
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.image import imread
import glob
import cv2

im = []
for filepath in glob.iglob(r'C:\Users\dan20\Pictures\wedding\beeri and adn. photo/*.jpg'):
    a = imread(filepath)
    b = cv2.resize(a, dsize = (456,304))
    im += [b]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i in im:
    time.sleep(2)    
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.imshow(i)
    plt.show()
```

For some reason I can't see the images as long as i use `time.sleep()`. 
How can I make each picture to appear for `N` amount of times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [plt.pause](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pause.html) :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = [np.random.random((9,9)) for i in range(1,6)]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i in im: 
    ax.cla()
    ax.imshow(i)
    ax.axis('off')
    plt.pause(2)
```

which gives :

[image: output_imshow]